# conversion of datetime Field to string in django queryset.values_list()?

Tags: django

my code:

```
from django.db.models import TextField
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value, CharField
qs=People.objects.annotate(
        formatted_date=Func(
            F('create_time'),
            Value('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
            function='to_char',
            output_field=TextField()
        )
    ).values('create_time').first()
print(qs)
```

but get data is

```
{'create_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 16, 15, 58, 10, 305730, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

i want to data is

```
{'create_time': "2020-12-02 17:12:12"}
```

my used database is mysql

Comment: `to_char` doesnt work because its Postgresql exclusive.

Comment: @ToniSredanović if use mysql  ,i will use func who is ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from django.db.models import TextField
    from django.db.models import F, Func, Value, CharField
    qs=People.objects.annotate(
            formatted_date=Func(
                F('create_time'),
                Value('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                function='FORMAT',
                output_field=TextField()
            )
        ).values('create_time').first()
    print(qs)
```

Comment: sorry, this result is 
{'create_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 16, 15, 58, 10, 305730, tzinfo=<UTC>)}

Comment: How about if u use `DATE_FORMAT` instead of `FORMAT`?